# Installing sublime-text 2 with pacman

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I want to install sublime-text 2 in Arch Linux with `pacman` package manager; how i can do this work?

Comment: You can't; it's in the AUR, not the official repos. Please read the wiki entry on the AUR.

Comment: @jasonwryan You can `pacman -U`.

Comment: @Sparhawk that only works after you have a package to install on your machine; which means learning how the AUR and `makepkg` work...

Comment: @jasonwryan Yes, that's true, but the installed package will still be managed by `pacman`, as opposed to `make install`ing it in unknown locations.

Comment: @Sparhawk ...and your point is? OP *still has to learn how the AUR works* in order to install sublime-text. Pacman won't do the work the way it does for *official repos*.

Comment: @jasonwryan I agree that they need to learn the AUR and that it's different to the official repos, but the question just asked how to use it with `pacman`. You cannot use `pacman -S`, but you can (and should) use `pacman -U`. My point was that you saying "you can't" is incorrect. However, perhaps I'm being too pedantic, because I definitely agree that they just need to read the wiki page! I wanted them to be clear that they should still use a package manager… but this will be evident after they read the wiki.

Answer (score 2):

Since `sublime-text` is a package in `AUR` you will need to install some pacman helper like `packer`. To install packer:

```
pacman -S base-devel fakeroot jshon expac git
#create a dir somewhere, eg. $HOME
mkdir ~/packer/
cd ~/packer
wget https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pa/packer/PKGBUILD
#Run makepkg on the PKGBUILD as a regular user
makepkg
#install the package with (as root)
pacman -U packer-*.pkg.tar.gz
```

Personally I go beyond this and also edit `~/.bashrc` to add some aliases like these:

```
alias pac="sudo /usr/bin/packer -S"             # default action        - install one or more packages
alias pacu="/usr/bin/packer -Syu"               # '[u]pdate'            - upgrade all packages to their newest version
alias pacs="/usr/bin/packer -Ss"                # '[s]earch'            - search for a package using one or more keywords
alias paci="/usr/bin/packer -Si"                # '[i]nfo'              - show information about a package
alias paclo="/usr/bin/packer -Qdt"              # '[l]ist [o]rphans'    - list all packages which are orphaned
alias pacc="sudo /usr/bin/packer -Scc"          # '[c]lean cache'       - delete all not currently installed package files
alias paclf="/usr/bin/packer -Ql"               # '[l]ist [f]iles'      - list all files installed by a given package
alias pacexpl="/usr/bin/packer -D --asexp"      # 'mark as [expl]icit'  - mark one or more packages as explicitly installed 
alias pacimpl="/usr/bin/packer -D --asdep"      # 'mark as [impl]icit'  - mark one or more packages as non explicitly installed
alias pacro="/usr/bin/packer -Qtdq > /dev/null && sudo /usr/bin/packer -Rs \$(/usr/bin/packer -Qtdq | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g')" #[r]emove [o]rphaned packages - BE CAREFULL
```

Comment: Well, technically you don't *need* to install a helper. You can manually install it the same way you installed packer (although in this case you'd need to download snapshot instead of just the PKGBUILD).

Answer (score -3):

```
sudo yaourt -S sublime-text-dev
```